# When using b-overlay in b-modal the modal body is not visible

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am using Vue Bootstrap and when I add b-overlay with no-wrap prop in b-modal the modal body is not visible even if the overlay is not active. Please see the example

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-worker-evcyd

I can use it without no-wrap prop but this way the modal footer and header are not overlaid

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're using the `no-wrap` property, which disabled the usage of the default slot in `<b-overlay>`.

You can read more here:
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/overlay#non-wrapping-mode

> By default,  wraps the content of the default slot. In some cases you may want to obscure a parent container. Use the no-wrap prop to disable rendering of the wrapping **(and ignore the default slot).**

If you need to use `no-wrap`, you need to place the content you want outside of `<b-overlay>`.

```html
<b-modal>
  <b-overlay no-wrap>
    <template #overlay>
      Overlay content here
    </template>
  </b-overlay>

  <div>Modal content</div>
</b-modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/overlay#using-in-b-modal), you can add body-class="position-static" on b-modal and rounded prop enabled. This will make the entire b-modal covered with overlay.